# Trouble with the QDBMP library in C

Tags: c, bitmap

Hi i recently was searching for a way to make bitmap image with C, so i found the [QDBMP](http://qdbmp.sourceforge.net/) library which look's easy but i've got a problem.
When i create a bmp image and a color, it stay black always, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "qdbmp.h"

void main() {

BMP* image = BMP_Create(640,480,8);
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<640;i++){
    for(j=0;j<640;j++){
        BMP_SetPixelRGB(image,i,j,10,20,100);
    }
}   

BMP_WriteFile(image,"image.bmp");
BMP_Free(image);
```

}

Comment: Apart from the issues pointed out below, you are attempting to write to non-existent pixels. Try changing `for(j=0;j<640;j++)` to `for(j=0;j<480;j++)`

Comment: Oh it's just a misstaping in my code it's 480, thank's anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use index color (8 bits depth), you must create a palette and use indexed color. See `BMP_SetPixelIndex` and `BMP_SetPaletteColor`

If you want a faster (I mean if you don't want to modify your code too much) result (but a bigger file) use 16 or 32 bits depth images.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an 8-bit BMP, the coloring uses a palette. Before you can set any color, you must first initialize the palette. The library provides:

```
void BMP_SetPaletteColor( BMP* bmp, UCHAR index, UCHAR r, UCHAR g, UCHAR b );
```

An 8 bit BMP has 256 palette entries:

```
for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    BMP_SetPaletteColor(image, i, i,i,i);
```

Next you use the following function to set the color:

```
void BMP_SetPixelIndex( BMP* bmp, UINT x, UINT y, UCHAR val );
```

Comment: Two errors: `BMP_SetPaleteColor` is misspelt (should be `BMP_SetPaletteColor`), and the number of arguments to this function call is also incorrect (you need another `i` to specify the index number; i.e. `(image, i,i,i,i);`)

Comment: Oh thank's a lot now i understand, the documentation didn't mention that.

Comment: @Abdellah-Sabiri, you could have used the library's error function to check what was happening. It would have probably returned an error (hopefully indicating what error).